# IISExpress remote access

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

**I'm trying to access an API (created with visual studio WebAPI) on a remote computer.** 
I've followed this guide (https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/805238/Access-IIS-Express-Website-From-Remote-Machine), and I can now access it locally with http://IP:Port but not remotely. *But it works when I disable the Firewall on my local PC, however I don't want it to be ad vitam aeternam opened*

- I've opened the port for ISS express like so in the guide, but it seems I need to open something else, I tried TCP and UDP inbound/outbound (TCP inboud was the one I opened with the guide), but it still don't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: “I've opened the port for IIS Express like so in the guide” is incorrect. The `netsh` commands showed in that article does not open any port on Windows Firewall, as they just create reserved URL in HTTP API for other purposes. Learn Windows Firewall via Google and you should be able to figure out.

Comment: Yes sorry, I followed more than one guide, I didn't notice that this one was incomplete, I followed this one also (https://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer), and I can ensure you I oppened the ports, thanks for the answer though !

Comment: Notice the "profile" concept in Windows Firewall. It can be complex and sometimes you can get it wrong. Do read more Microsoft documentation to learn that. Individual blog posts are usually messy on completeness and correctness.

Comment: I had also opened the ports manually via the firewall and selectioned all the profiles, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: "It doesn't work" does not help much. What exactly is the error you got from a web browser from another machine? Tools like Wireshark can also provide more information if you install on both machines and capture packets together.

Comment: I would suggest our VS extension called Conveyor https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti it has a tunnelling service that will do what you need without messing with the firewall.  Oh and it is free.